# How to create a month iterator

Tags: python

I would like to create a python function that would allow me to iterate over the months from a start point to a stop point.  For example it would look something like

```
def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
```

Calling `months(8, 2010, 3, 2011)` would return:

```
((8, 2010), (9, 2010), (10, 2010), (11, 2010), (12, 2010), (1, 2011), (2, 2011), (3, 2011))
```

The function could just return a tuple of tuples, but I would love to see it as a generator (ie using `yield`).

I've checked the `calendar` python module and it doesn't appear to provide this functionality.  I could write a nasty `for` loop to do it easily enough, but I'm interested to see how gracefully it could be done by a pro.

Thanks.

Comment: Why shouldn't a professional write some code using two nested loops. Better readable somewhat more verbose code than dense and tricky code using fancy language features that are hard to understand after one day.

Comment: Well the solution most certainly would involve at least one for loop, but the only approach I can think of also involves all sorts of ifs, ie, `if start_year == end_year` , `if end_year - start_year > 1`, etc...  It just seems like there is a more beautiful solution than that.

Comment: The `dateutil` module could be useful here

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The calendar works like this.

```
def month_year_iter( start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year ):
    ym_start= 12*start_year + start_month - 1
    ym_end= 12*end_year + end_month - 1
    for ym in range( ym_start, ym_end ):
        y, m = divmod( ym, 12 )
        yield y, m+1
```

All multiple-unit things work like this.  Feet and Inches, Hours, Minutes and Seconds, etc., etc.  The only thing that's **not** this simple is months-days or months-weeks because months are irregular.  Everything else is regular, and you need to work in the finest-grained units.

Comment: That's the beauty I was looking for. I absolutely never thought about it like that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great answer, but all regular things do not work *exactly* like this, in the sense of having to add and subtract 1 because months are numbered from 1..12 instead of 0..11 (like feet and inches).

Comment: @martineau: True.  But all things work out well in their finest grained units.  (Except months, which are irregular). The ±1 is an encoding nuance that's often obvious.  From your comment, I gather it's not always obvious.

Comment: @martineau:  It's not really a "subtlety".  But thanks.  I'm sure someone is confused by ordinal and cardinal numbers.

Comment: To get the days in a month (including the leap year special cases), Python has a handy [calendar.monthrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) function.

Comment: I think there is a small bug here as the last element will be `(2011, 2)` and not `(2011, 3)` with `month_year_iter(8, 2010, 3, 2011)` (Need to add +1 to the range). Otherwise works great!

Comment: `ym_end= 12*end_year + end_month - 1` needs to be `ym_end= 12*end_year + end_month`, to fix end month. Otherwise, great method!

Answer (score 20):

`months` function using the `dateutil` module

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from datetime import datetime

def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    start = datetime(start_year, start_month, 1)
    end = datetime(end_year, end_month, 1)
    return [(d.month, d.year) for d in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start, until=end)]
```

Example Usage

```
print months(11, 2010, 2, 2011)
#[(11, 2010), (12, 2010), (1, 2011), (2, 2011)]
```

Or in iterator form

```
def month_iter(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    start = datetime(start_year, start_month, 1)
    end = datetime(end_year, end_month, 1)

    return ((d.month, d.year) for d in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start, until=end))
```

Iterator usage

```
for m in month_iter(11, 2010, 2, 2011):
    print m
    #(11, 2010)
    #(12, 2010)
    #(1, 2011)
    #(2, 2011)
```

Comment: Just to note, [**`dateutil`**](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a third party module.

Answer (score 20):

Since others have already provided code for generators, I wanted to add that Pandas has a method called '[period_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html#pandas.period_range)' that, in this case, can take in a starting and end, year and month, and return a period index, suitable for iteration.

```
import pandas as pd

pr = pd.period_range(start='2010-08',end='2011-03', freq='M')

prTupes=tuple([(period.month,period.year) for period in pr])

#This returns: ((8, 2010), (9, 2010), (10, 2010), (11, 2010), (12, 2010), (1, 2011), (2, 2011), (3, 2011))
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the elegance or speed of this could be improved, but it's the straightforward solution:

```
def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    month, year = start_month, start_year
    while True:
        yield month, year
        if (month, year) == (end_month, end_year):
            return
        month += 1
        if (month > 12):
            month = 1
            year += 1
```

EDIT: And here's a less straightforward one that avoids even needing to use `yield` by using a generator comprehension:

```
def months2(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    return (((m_y % 12) + 1, m_y / 12) for m_y in
            range(12 * start_year + start_month - 1, 12 * end_year + end_month))
```

Comment: Probably best to make the end month exclusive, like range. See also: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Comment: Agreed, I was just matching the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of dfan's approach, and also a simpler solution than S. Lott's (no division, no modulo):

```
def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):

    month, year = start_month, start_year

    while (year, month) <= (end_year, end_month):

        yield month, year

        month += 1
        if month > 12:
            month = 1
            year += 1
```

This approach is close to the method one would use if they had to do this by hand.  It runs in the same amount of time as S. Lott's (the tests in the code above take about as much time as a division and a modulo).

Answer (score 2):

```
    for year in range(2017, 2021):
        for month in range(1, 13):
            this_month = datetime.date.today().replace(year=year, month=month, day=1)
```

Comment: wouldn't this just repeat months 'start_month_number' onwards for each year instead of resetting to month=1 for everytime year is changed in outer loop ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as short as the other solutions, but it's straightforward to understand. Basically, it has two branches.

- The start year is the same as the end year
- The start year is different from the end year

The latter case has three phases:

- From the start month to December of the start year
- Every month from each year between the start year to the end year
- From January to the end month of the end year

If the end year is the year after the start year, the second phase above is skipped (no need for an explicit test, the range is simply empty).

```
def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    if start_year == end_year:
        for month in xrange(start_month, end_month+1):
           yield month, start_year
    else:
        for month in xrange(start_month, 13):
            yield month, start_year
        for year in xrange(start_year+1, end_year):
            for month in xrange(1, 13):
               yield month, year
        for month in xrange(1, end_month+1):
           yield end_month, end_year
```

For Python 3.x, change `xrange` to `range`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous in that you ask for an iterator, but then show a function returning a tuple of tuples. So here's both:

```
import calendar
import datetime

def months_iter(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    start_date = datetime.date(start_year, start_month, 1)
    end_date = datetime.date(end_year, end_month, 1)
    date = start_date
    while date <= end_date:
        yield (date.month, date.year)
        days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]
        date += datetime.timedelta(days_in_month)

def months(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year):
    return tuple(d for d in months_iter(start_month, start_year, end_month, end_year))

print months(8, 2010, 3, 2011)

# ((8, 2010), (9, 2010), (10, 2010), (11, 2010), (12, 2010), (1, 2011), (2, 2011), (3, 2011))
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a little fun with Python built-in iterators, but certainly not elegant ;)

from datetime import timedelta, date

```
class MonthRange:
    def __init__ (self, date1, date2):
        self.start_date = date1 - timedelta(days=1)
        self.end_date = date2
        self.data = self.start_date
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.data >= self.end_date.replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32):
            raise StopIteration
        ret = self.data
        self.data = self.data + timedelta(days=32)
        return ret.replace(day=1)

for x in MonthRange(date.today(), date(2012, 11, 01)):
    print (x.year, x.month)
```